# how to find the source of a java package/class

Tags: maven

Working on a large legacy maven based project.

some classes import `com.example.somenamespace.someclass`, which is nowhere to be found on the dependency list on pom.xml

`mvn dependency:tree` do not show anything even close to that namespace. How do I figure out what is making maven to pull that jar?

Comment: Via the dependency tree, but there's no direct tie to Maven package naming to packages it might include, e.g., my artifact could be under `com.davelnewton.foo` while the imported jar may contain classes in a `com.davelnewton.foo` package, and/or `org.apache.whatever` packages, and so on. You can always `jar tvf | grep ...` on all dependencies (or whatever jar stuff is; I don't recall).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not quite a Maven answer, but I think it will be useful to you.

If an artifact comes from Maven Central, you can [search Maven Central by fully-qualified classname](https://search.maven.org/classic/#advancedsearch%7Cgav).

Your question refers to a class, which of course will not ever appear in `mvn dependency:tree`, which deals exclusively with artifacts.